# Fabricate v. Fabulous (or Fable)

Tags: meaning, etymology

Both of these words begin with the same three letters, and both of them seem to come from Latin (according to http://www.etymonline.com) both in the 15th c. I'm wondering if there is any connection from further back?

Work is kinda slow today.

Comment: You don't have to go beyond etymonline. Their entry for ***fabricate*** says *see **fabric***, which they say is [from Proto-Italic **fafro-,** from PIE **dhabh-** "to fit together"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fabric&allowed_in_frame=0). And their entry for ***fabulous***, which says [from Latin **fabulosus** "celebrated in fable;" also "rich in myths," from **fabula** "story, tale"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fabulous&searchmode=none) includes *see **fable***, which it says is *from PIE root **bha-** (2) "speak" (see **fame** (n.))*

Comment: It's really nice having that PIE root level for etymologies, isn't it? Gives a completely different perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, they both are etymologically different. They originated from different Latin words.
Fabricate from "fabricatus" and Fabulous from "fabulosus". 
Source:http://oxforddictionaries.com/